# С помощью вложенных циклов, сделать рисунок

Tags: javascript, html, css

С помощью вложенных циклов, сделать рисунок:
прошу обяснить в чем ошибка

```
*****
****
***
**
*

function t8() {
    let out = document.querySelector('out-8');
    let a = '';
    for(i = 5; i <= 0; i--) {
        for ( k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
            a += '*';
        }
        a += '</br>';
    }
    out.innerHTML = a;
}

document.querySelector('.b-8').onclick = t8;
```

Comment: `for(i = 5; i <= 0;` — перед началом каждой итерации будет проверться условие `i <= 0`... 5 < 0 → false, цикл никогда не начинается.

Comment: спасибо тепер понимаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ошибка в строке
   let out = document.querySelector('out-8');
   Селектор оформлен неправильно
2. Ошибка условия в строке
   for(i = 5; i <= 0; i--) {
   здесь нет ни одной итерации
3. Вызов по клику лучше вешать через eventListener

```js
function t8() {
    let out = document.querySelector('.out-8');
    let a = '';
    for(i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
        for ( k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
            a += '*';
        }
        a += '</br>';
    }
    out.innerHTML = a;
}

document.querySelector('.b-8').addEventListener( 'click', t8 );
```

```html
<button class="b-8">
some
</button>
<div class="out-8">

</div>
```

Comment: спасибо уже разобрался нужно было раньше в консоль заглянуть

Answer (score 1):

```js
function t8() {
  let a = '';
  for (i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
    for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
      a += '*';
    }
    a += '\n';
  }
  return a;
}

console.log(t8());
```